# Is metric tool in eclipse counting ternary operator complexity?

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs, ternary, metric

I am using sonarQube(**third party analyzer-Findbug**) at server and metric tool for calculating cyclomatic complexity at local computer. SonarQube is calculating the complexity for the following code but  metric is not counting it.I am using metric version 1.3.8.

**(isChecked() ? 1 : 0), (isRemove() ? 1 : 0), (isSuspend() ? 1 : 0)**

So do I need to use some other tool in eclipse?Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,sonarQube does count ternary operator complexity and Metric doesn't count ternary operator complexity